# Serving an image from behind a firewall with Ruby/Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, firewall, vpn

I have a webapp that I've started writing in Sinatra that will need to fetch images and display them in HTML.

The images are fetched from an API that sits behind a firewall along with the web server my Sinatra site sits on.  The API returns JSON that contains URLs to images residing behind the firewall.

I can't simply plop these URLs into img tags in my views since they are not public facing.

I'm wondering how to best get around this.  Some way for me to fetch the images and cache them on my Sinatra server so that they are public facing?

Very new to both Sinatra and Ruby.

Comment: could you make progress on your issue? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you have a route to get images from the API?

Example:

```
get '/image/:image_name' do
    content_type 'image/png'

    API::get_image(params[:image_name])
end
```

Then you would have to rewrite the urls in your image tags to use this route.

Hope this helps

PS: also make sure that the :image_name that can be passes will not be a security hole to the API. Make sure that it will only allow urls that 'make sense' or that the API has security measures that it only accepts calls to images and not sensible data.

Comment: I think something like this will work.  User auth token and userid will be retrieved from cookies and checked before making call to API for the image to pass back.  Thanks!